# How to convert Swift optional NSNumber to optional Int? (any improvements on my code?)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, option-type, nsnumber

What would be the shortest/cleanest way to convert an Optional Number to an Optional Int in Swift?

Is there a better way than this? (see below)

```
let orderNumberInt : Int?
if event.orderNum != nil {
    orderNumberInt = Int(event.orderNum!)
} else {
    orderNumberInt = nil
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think most easiest way is

```
var orderNumberInt = orderNum?.intValue
```

Also, you can do it like this

```
var orderNum:NSNumber? = NSNumber(int: 12)
var orderNumberInt:Int? = (orderNum != nil) ? Int(orderNum!) : nil
print(orderNumberInt)
```

Comment: int is the initialiser for Int32

Comment: thanks guys - you made it hard to choose which was correct first :)   But what I'm after specifically here would be "var orderNumberInt  = orderNum?.integerValue" so I choose this one, hope thats ok

Comment: FYI, this method has been renamed from `integerValue` to `intValue` in Swift 4.

Answer (score 5):

```
let number:NSNumber? = NSNumber(integer: 125)


if let integerValue = number?.integerValue {
    print(integerValue)
}

let integerValue = number?.integerValue ?? 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
orderNumberInt = orderNum?.intValue
```

This is the best way to do it in Swift.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1412554-intvalue

Answer (score 0):

You can use if let syntax

```
    var number: NSNumber?
    if let value = number as? Int {
        // get int value
    } else {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this simple conversion:

```
// lets consider following vars
var nsNum: NSNumber?
var oiNum: Int? // oi - optional Int
```

**NSNumber to optional Int?**

```
nsNum = NSNumber.init(value: 18)
oiNum = nsNum as? Int
```

**optional Int? to NSNumber**

```
oiNum = 19
nsNum = oiNum as NSNumber?
```

p.s. I am new to swift, so if something wrong, feel free to correct :-)